# Is it better to disclude your age when submitting to a publisher if you are young?

Tags: publishing, publisher

Does including your age, if you are a young author, give you a disadvantage?

Comment: People do not normally disclose their age when submitting to publishers. However, you will have an issue if you are offered publication and you are two young to sign a contract. At that point you would have to disclose your age and have your parent sign the contract for you.

Answer (score 2):

Publishers select manuscripts by two factors: quality of the writing and marketability of the author. President Obama can write a very bad book and it will become a bestseller. He is a most marketable author.

Being a teenager (or even younger) is a strong point in marketability. There are many examples of fair to good books that became bestsellers simply because their authors were around 15 when they wrote them. A recent US-American example is *Eragon* by Christopher Paolini, which has been reviewed as a mediocre book but topped the international bestseller lists.

#### Young age in fact gives you an advantage.

Comment: I am being accused of being mentally fourteen on a daily basis. Does that count? :-D

Comment: I'm on the fence on this answer.  Being young isn't a selling point by itself, being young BUT also writing well is, because it's rare.  If Paolini seems like a counterexample, remember that he only got his contract after self-marketing himself successfully to other young people.  He likely wouldn't have been signed by a publisher otherwise.

Comment: @ChrisSunami Paolini's book was accidentally picked up during their holiday by the wife of an author of his later publisher. This author then recommended the book to his publisher, because his wife pushed him to it (because their child enjoyed the book, I think). Paolini had not much success marketing his self-published book and did not manage to go beyond local sales. Paolini tells the story somewhere on the web (and I have linked to it in several of my answers and comments). Google it.